# Selenium "chrome not reachable" error and can't access browser web elements after test kills existing browser and launches new

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Selenium "chrome not reachable" error and can't access browser web elements after test kills existing browser and launches new

I'm using latest java, chrome driver and selenium 3.0 latest jar for automating web application, everything works very fine except when test fails; it kills browser according to my requirement and new test uses new browser but chrome shows unreachable.

Now is there any binding to previous session? How subsequent browser launch can't identify web objects and it works fine for first first launch only? Does anyone have solution for this or can anyone try in your framework after killing existing browser and launching new in between of the test using latest GA or beta web driver version?

## Steps:

```
 - Write below code and launch chrome using web driver
 - Navigate to your web application
 - Login to it (WORKS FINE)
 - Assume test fails, so it kills existing chrome browser
 - Again hits below code and opens new browser
 - Navigate to application again
 - Login to it (DOESN'T WORK - because it can't identify web objects for newly launched browser due to "chrome not reachable" error).
```

## Code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromedriverPath);
webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
webDriver.navigate().to(myURL);
WebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input[class=LoginButton]))
```

## Error:

```
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '2aa21c1', time: '2016-08-02 14:59:43 -0700'
System info: host: 'abc', ip: '12.116.61.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_102'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129), userDataDir=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7360_5203}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=52.0.2743.116, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 4d9e503ddb4ae1506b1592a0426bb7ff
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=input[class=LoginButton]}
129615 [main] INFO com.util.SleepUtil  - Sleep: 1000 milliseconds ... (0/1000)
130615 [main] INFO com.util.SleepMetrics  - Entry: com.selenium.functions.Login.NavigateTo() - Sleep: 1000/2000
130615 [main] INFO com.framework - ...WebDriver...findElement()
130615 [main] INFO com.framework - ...WebDriver...elementPresent()
130615 [main] INFO com.framework - ...WebDriver...getElementOrNull()
130615 [main] INFO com.framework - ...WebDriver...getElementByCss()
130615 [main] INFO com.framework - ...WebDriver...configureCssLocator()
132629 [main] INFO com.framework - ...WebDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input[class=LoginButton]))
135651 [main] INFO com.framework - ...getElementByCss()...org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: chrome not reachable
```

Comment: Why have you set the system property to null.....    String chromedriverPath = null;
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",chromedriverPath);

Comment: Thanks for your comment, there were null checking additional code which i had removed so people understand it properly but that has nothing to with it because browser is launched fine and meanwhile modified the code so it doesn't misguide.